# What is the name of this effect, and what is a good way to replicate it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, terminology

See how the image background fades with the black menu bar? I see this effect very often and I like it a lot. I would love a tutorial (either Photoshop or Illustrator) or how-to article but I don´t even know how to search for it.

[image: dots mask effect]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As farray said, its halftone pattern, there are many ways of creating the same,

You can see this [guide for halftone pattern](http://2photoshop.com/guide-to-the-halftone-pattern/)(this is quite hard and long)

but you can also create this using Photoshop filters within minutes, i have posted a SS to make it clear to you,

[image: htp]
(open in new window for clarity)
you can use this before your image just put this layer and reduce it's opacity.
Hope this will help..

Comment: In addition to Jack's information, if you have a photograph, you can achieve a halftone by converting it to grayscale, then to bitmap.

Answer (score 5):

It's called "halftone".  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halftone

Answer (score 1):

There are many tutorials online, both video and static. [This page](http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tutorials-effects/photoshop-halftone-effect/) does a pretty good step-by-step. I would google "halftone + photoshop" or "halftone + illustrator".